# Moving from Cart to Order

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I am having difficulty moving the user's cart over to being an order. I understand that a cart is essentially an order with `isCompleted` set to `false` and no date set but I can't seem to access anything when setting `orders = craft.commerce.orders`, etc. I can see the cart on the backend along with the guest's email but cannot get orders. I can easily get the current cart and all my products have a price of $0 if that is relevant.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this in the context of a plugin (PHP) or the front-end (Twig)? Can you provide some relevant template/PHP code to show what you're currently doing?

Comment: This is using twig. Currently I'm using {% set cart = craft.commerce.cart %} and then successfully adding to it through my product pages using a POST for /updateCart. After the user has added all the items he/she wants then I want them to be able to checkout... or at least move to a different order status so I can have an email sent.

Answer (score 1):

`craft.commerce.orders` returns an element criteria model that defaults to setting the criteria param `isCompleted` to true.

You would need to set `isCompleted` to false on the criteria to override it, in order to get someone else's cart from the front-end.